# Three js camera with gyroscope ( deviceorientation event)

Tags: three.js, 3d, gyroscope

I have a camera animation for desktop which goes like this:
in mousemove event I have

```
mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 100;
mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 100;
```

and in the render function I have

```
camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
```

I want to achieve the same effect with a mobile gyroscope. I tried this:

in the deviceorientation event

```
gammaRotation = event.gamma;
betaRotation = event.beta;
```

and in the renderer function I have mostly the same thing as with the desktop version

```
camera.position.x += (gammaRotation/100 - camera.position.x) * 0.05; 
camera.position.y += (-betaRotation/100 - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
```

But when the beta is 90 ( thats when the phone is vertical to the ground 90 degrees) my camera jumps to one site to another and then goes back to working correctly. It only "jumps" when beta is 90.
I guess it's a math error, but can't really work it out because I don't know how to enable inspector for Iphone right now...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing the `deviceorientation` data. The `alpha, beta, gamma` properties of the event [represents device rotations around the `z, x, y` axes respectively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent), so you should assign them to the camera's rotation, not its position, like [in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_deviceorientation).

The jump from 90 to -90 is to be expected with rotations in 3D space for the same reason that a 2D rotation of +180 is the same as -180. There are multiple ways to describe the same rotation, so you can't convert rotations into positions reliably.

Comment: The link "in this demo" is invalid. The demo appears to have been removed.